# ¿como puedo enviar una tabla completa de sqlite a mysql en android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

necesito enviar toda la informacion de mi tabla:

```
String create_aguacate_table = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_AGUACATE + " (" + COLUMN_IDAGUACATE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + COLUMN_CALIBREAGUACATE + " TEXT, "+ COLUMN_PRECIOAGUACATE + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_PORCENTAJEAGUACATE + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_RESULTADOAGUACATE + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(create_aguacate_table);
```

¿como puedo enviar todos los datos?

Comment: tabla completa te referís con la estructura con todos los registros??

Comment: asi es, ¿como lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Hace la consulta y guarda todos los registros en el Gson. Luego manda ese Gson remotamente a tu servidor donde se encuentra tu servidor MySQL. En tu Servidor MySQL debes de capturar lo que enviás y colocar en la base de datos. Tiene muchos pasos

Comment: ¿tienes algún ejemplo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que debes tener en cuenta es que tu tabla tiene un fotmato, por lo tanto para que sea ordenado deberias crear una clase con los mismos atributos.

```
public class TuClase {
       int id;
       String nombre;
}
```

Esto es un ejemplo pero tu sabes los campos que requieres. Una vez tengas esta clase y sus metodos constructores y sus `get` and `set` haces un `ArrayList` del tipo `TuClase`.

```
ArrayList<TuClase> lista = new ArrayList<TuClase>();
if (cursor .moveToFirst()) {
    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(id));
        String nombre = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(nombre));
        TuClase objeto = new Objeto(id,nombre);
        list.add(objeto);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
 }
```

Asi obtienes todos los registros y los tienes en una lista, teniendo esta lista puedes enviarla a tu servidor dependiendo como la recibas, lo mejor seria un json.

```
JSONArray jsonArrayMiLista = new JSONArray(lista);
```